# Factorial in TCL

Tags: tcl

As i am new with TCL, So need some help.

Need to write a program for factorial, square-root, square, cube and cube-root of any given number (let it be 10). Without using the keys eg: sqrt.

Thankyou.

Comment: You want to write a program without pressing keys? (And for factorial, how large a value to want to go up to?)

Answer (score 2):

Most of those operations can be done with the `**` operator:

```
set x 7
set square [expr { $x ** 2 }]
set square_root [expr { $x ** (1.0 / 2) }]
set cube [expr { $x ** 3 }]
set cube_root [expr { $x ** (1.0 / 3) }]
```

Factorials can be calculated in [many ways](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factorial#Tcl).

Comment: You could also use the `pow` function; the `**` operator is just a wrapper round that (when called with at least one floating-point argument).

Answer (score 0):

A recursive implementation of factorial:

```
proc fac {n} {
    if { $n == 0 } {
        return 1
    } else {
        return [expr {$n*[fac [expr {$n-1}]]}]
    }
}
```

And a iterative version:

```
proc fac {n} {
    set result 1
    for { set i 1 } { $i <= $n } { incr i } {
        set result [expr {$result * $i}]
    }
    return $result
}
```